# CASE WHEN NULL makes wrong result in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, null

I have a table with a column of image type, the table has some rows but all the rows haven't had any image yet, they are all null. To test the CASE WHEN NULL, I've tried this and it gave a strange result:

```
SELECT CASE myImageColumn WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM myTable
```

All the returned rows were in a column of 1's (I thought 0's). What is wrong here?

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Because null is unknown, nothing is equal to null.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Thank you, I know you could give me a solution but instead just comment it here and another one has answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: Lamak's answer is perfect.  I don't know SQLLite very well, so I dared not post an answer that didn't work :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can't compare with `NULL` like that, you should try:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN myImageColumn IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
FROM myTable
```

Comment: This doesn't work in MS SQL Server, do you know the solution for SQL Server? Thanks!

Comment: Also doesn't work with SQLite as far as I can see.

Answer (score 8):

Use a different form of `CASE` instead:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  myImageColumn IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM myTable
```

Two useful links:

- http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html
- http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: Thank you, you are a little late after I said thanks to Lamak. But give you my +1. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bypass:

```
CASE ifnull(myValue, 'someUniqueStringOrValue')
  WHEN 'someUniqueStringOrValue' THEN 0 -- this means null
  WHEN 'someNormalValue' THEN 1
END
```

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.